# Can we split "What is the theology behind bodily relics?"

Tags: discussion

> What was the original theology justifying taking them? Did protestants introduce a counter-theology? Did the Catholic Church alter its theology on the matter in recent times?

Can we make *Did protestants introduce a counter-theology [to the adoration of relics]?* a separate question, and take [this answer](https://christianity.stackexchange.com/a/26844/4188) with it?

---

My assumption is that a moderator can do it in one step, including moving the answer; if I'm correct, it would be cleaner than asking a new question, and then asking @jlaverde to copy-paste his answer and delete the old one.

Comment: I have to say (so here is as good a place as any) that I get really fed up with answers not answering the question asked: "Why do Catholics do X?" "They shouldn't, because Y".

Comment: Agreed. It's disrespectful at best.

Answer (score 2):

What will have to happen will be the new question will have to be asked, and then the answer copy/pasted over to the new question. There isn't a mechnical way for us to cleave questions apart, only to put them together.